# short string representing Viewstate Visible even if view state on each and every control is disabled

Tags: asp.net

I disabled the viewstate on page and each control within it. But I still see short string representing the viewstate in the page source.

I created a page with two controls, one a checkbox and other a texbox. I completely disabled the viewstate for both the controls and the page. But I still see a div rendered which contains the viewstate in the hidden variable:

```
<div class="aspNetHidden"> <input id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" 
    value="/wEPDwUKMTcwNTQzMjY4MWQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFG‌​
    2N0bDAwJE1haW5Db250ZW50JGNoYm94VGVzdPRq7jJUwzyCcKYfAFB/seRcAvziSp3bKL23H9U7O9sU" 
    name="__VIEWSTATE"> </div>
```

Can anyone help in understanding this behaviour of asp.net

Comment: Would you please provide your markup ..

Comment: I created a page with two controls, one a checkbox and other a texbox. I completely disabled the viewstate for both the controls and the page. But I still see a div rendered which contains the viewstate in the hidden variable <div class="aspNetHidden">

<input id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value="/wEPDwUKMTcwNTQzMjY4MWQYAQUeX19Db250cm9sc1JlcXVpcmVQb3N0QmFja0tleV9fFgEFG2N0bDAwJE1haW5Db250ZW50JGNoYm94VGVzdPRq7jJUwzyCcKYfAFB/seRcAvziSp3bKL23H9U7O9sU" name="__VIEWSTATE">
</div>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) You must have a server-side form tag () in your ASPX page if you want to use ViewState. A form field is required so the hidden field that contains the ViewState information can post back to the server. And, it must be a server-side form so the ASP.NET page framework can add the hidden field when the page is executed on the server.
2) The page itself saves 20 or so bytes of information into ViewState, which it uses to distribute PostBack data and ViewState values to the correct controls upon postback. So, even if ViewState is disabled for the page or application, you may see a few remaining bytes in ViewState.
3) In cases where the page does not post back, you can eliminate ViewState from a page by omitting the server side tag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972427.aspx

It's the control state.

If you really want to get rid of viewstate and controlstate you can use this code in the code-behind for the page, or in any class that the code-behind derives from

```
class MyPage : Page {
    private class DummyPageStatePersister : PageStatePersister {
        public DummyPageStatePersister(Page p) : base(p) {}
        public override void Load() {}
        public override void Save() {}
    }
    private DummyPageStatePersister _PageStatePersister;
    protected override PageStatePersister PageStatePersister {
        get {
            if (_PageStatePersister == null)
                _PageStatePersister = new DummyPageStatePersister(this);
            return _PageStatePersister;
        }
    }

    // other stuff comes here
}
```

Be very careful when doing this, though, since you're violating the contract with the controls. MSDN explicitly states that control state is always available. In practice, however, it has worked for me.

**Edit:**
Since I was downvoted, I like to point out again: Don't do this unless you know exactly what you are doing. In my case, almost the entire application was written in client-side javascript, and on those few occations where postbacks occurred, I always used the Request.Form collection to retrieve the values. **Do not use server-side controls for anything but simple rendering if you do this.**

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not get rid of View State completely. You will always have a relatively short string representing the page itself even if you turn off the view state on each and every control.

Check [State Management (View State)](http://interview-preparation-for-you.blogspot.com/2010/04/state-managementview-state.html).

Comment: can you tell me the section in the entire article which I should refer to get answer of questions.

Comment: Yeah..Search for "Can I Get Rid Of View State Completely?" in the article.

Comment: I know that I can't get rid of it, my question is what behavior of asp.net causes this. looking at your article , can't find a place that explains this. Also, when putting up answers please provide some level of explanation from your side rather than putting some blog's link

Comment: please check my another answer and let me now if this is fine ?